# Fetch API: Handling a bad URL

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to bullet-proof some code which takes user input  and attempts to fetch data from a URL.

I have something like the following:

```
fetch(url)
.then(response=>{
    console.log(response.ok);
    response.text();
})
.catch(error=>console.log(error));
```

There’s more afterwards in the actual code.

If I enter something like `http://rubbish` I catch a `TypeError` which I can handle. If I enter something like `rubbish` (without the `http://` protocol), I get an error like :

```
GET file:///…/rubbish net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

and *then* get my `TypeError`. The actual error occurs on the first line of the code above, before the `catch()` block.

What is the correct way to handle an error like this?

I’m doing this in an Electron App, so one thing I don’t have to worry about is browser compatibility.

Comment: do you mean that URL should be always be absolute URL?

Comment: Can you check for the protocol `^https?:\/\/` in the input and prepend if missing?

Comment: @skyboyer It has to be since, it will be running as a desktop app. However, I can see that it might be interpreting the string as a relative URL?

Comment: @Anthony I can easily do that if I have to. Does `fetch()` have nothing else?

Comment: @Manngo Can you check `response.status === 404` in the `then()`?

Comment: I tried, but, of course, it doesn’t get there. I get the error in the first line, and then I catch the `TypeError`.

Comment: hmm attempting to reproduce on jsfiddle has `fetch('rubbish')` going to `https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/rubbish` with a 404 so I guess the `file://` protocol doesn't have that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200787/discussion-between-anthony-and-manngo).

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially execute different logic in the `catch` block depending on the type of error.  For example:

```
fetch(url)
.then(response=>{
    console.log(response.ok);
    response.text();
})
.catch(
    if (err instanceof TypeError) {
        // Handle this normally
    } else {
        // Execute other logic depending on the type of error you are receiving
    }
);
```

Hope this helps, good luck :)

Comment: According to the Console, the error occurs in the line that does the fetch. The `catch` is picking up the exception.